# MSG_MORE in send of unix stream socket is not effective on the peer's recv

Tags: c, sockets, epoll, unix-socket

**Here is some background about the issue that I have:**

I have a unix socket of type stream `server_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)`. On server side, the socket is `listen(2)`ed to via `listen(server_fd, 128)` and bound to an epoll handler that handles `EPOLLIN`. When reading from said socket (using the epoll callback), I use `accept(2)` to create a new socket for the *client* which is bound to its own epoll handling `EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT | EPOLLHUP | EPOLLERR`. So far pretty standard.

**Here is the problem:**

Because the data on server side is dispersed through multiple sources, and the aim is for client side to get the data in neat packages, I do something with a gist like this:

```
void **data_portions = NULL;
size_t *sz_data_portions = NULL;
size_t cnt_data_portions = 0;
/// ... Fill the variables above based on the needs
fill_data(&data_portions, &sz_data_portions, &cnt_data_portions);
for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt_data_portions; i++) {
    int flags = 0;
    if (i < cnt_data_portions - 1) {
        flags = MSG_MORE;
    }
    send(fd_peer, data_portions[i], sz_data_portions[i], flags);
}
```

efficiently, server sends `data_portions` content one by one all with the flag `MSG_MORE` except for the last one with no flags. suffice to say, server successfully sends all the data.

Now lets assume the specific scenario, namely `cnt_data_portions = 2` and `sz_data_portions = {128, 32}`. meaning that there are two calls to `send(2)`. First one with `len = 128` and `flags = MSG_MORE` and second one with `len = 32` and `flags = 0`.

Because I have used the `MSG_MORE` for the first call, on the client side I expect to be able to read `128 + 32 = 160` bytes in one shot using `recv(2)`. However, client side can only read `128` bytes only from the socket. This goes against the spirit of `MSG_MORE`. I don't understand why the client cannot read all `160` bytes in one shot.

**More info:**

- sockets are non-blocking (`O_NONBLOCK`) allowing address reuse (`SO_REUSEADDR` set to 1).
- sunpath is `"/tmp/test-socket"`.
- `bind(2)` is used to bind the socket to sunpath on server side and `connect(2)` is used on client side
- `SO_RCVBUF` and `SO_SNDBUF` are both set to 1 MB
- I put debugs one both server and clients side. I even made sure that all portions of data are sent before client attempts to read anything. Still, same issue happens.

**UPDATE**

The reason that I was trying to `send` with `MSG_MORE` is that I wanted to gather data from different sources into one message. For that I switched to `sendmsg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the linux [`unix(7)` man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html):

> The `send(2)` `MSG_MORE` flag is not supported by UNIX domain sockets.

and also of interest:

> The `SO_SNDBUF` socket option does have an effect for UNIX domain sockets, but the `SO_RCVBUF` option does not.

---

So there's no point in using `MSG_MORE` in your code; it's for TCP and UDP sockets.

Also, the number of reads on a stream (Be it a TCP socket, UNIX domain socket, pipe, etc.) isn't related to the number of writes on the far end. You have to include things like message boundaries in a higher-level protocol that uses the stream. If doing that is an issue, you might look into a `SOCK_SEQPACKET` unix socket instead, combined with `writev(2)` to send scattered data (I *think* that'll cause all the data to be in a single packet).

Comment: Thanks Shawn. Seems like I misunderstood the point of MSG_MORE completely